# setContentView causes crash

Tags: android

I'm trying the very first tutorial on the android website
[here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

The goal is to enter a text and ship it to a next page to display it.

However, I always get "Unfortunately My First App has stopped".

I noticed that when I comment out `setContentView(textView);` it works.

Here is my code: (LogCat stopped showing problems for some reason so I can't give the log)

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
     // setContentView(textView);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
       }

    }
```

Comment: move this two line to first line of onCreate() method and post logcat error.  `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code and post the logcat.

```
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.TextView;

            public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

                    // Get the message from the intent
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

                    // Create the text view
                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    textView.setTextSize(40);
                    textView.setText(message);

                   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
                   }

               }
}
```

I think need to declare TextView also in xml.
I hope this will help. Thanks!

Comment: i think you need `setContentView(textView);` after set text to TextView, because you create new TextView and don't use that on layout,

Answer (score 2):

This lines should be right after your onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

Try that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `setContentView()` before `super.onCreate()`.

Generally, `super.onCreate()` should be the first line in your overridden `onCreate()`.

Note that you already have `setContentView()` later that overrides your commented-out `setContentView()` content view.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is while creating  new android activity for `DisplayMessageActivity`, make sure its Hierarchical parent is selected as the `MainActivity`.